# How to properly reset Vue Composition Api's reactive values

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm wondering how should I reset a reactive in vuejs setup? (i know if change it to the ref and using view.value will solve this problem, but there should be an answer to this for using reactive)

```js
setup(props, context){
  // states
  const DataTable = reactive((null as unknown) as DataTable);
  const PolicyForm = reactive((null as unknown) as PolicyForm);
  let view = reactive(resetViewState());
  let config = reactive(
    (resetPreRegisterConfig() as unknown) as PreRegisterConfig
  );
  // methods:
  const fetchProfilelist = (
    pagination: Pagination{ page:1, size:15},
    sort_label: string = ""
  ) => {
    DataTable.fetchTablelist(api_fetchProfilelist, pagination, sort_label);
  };
  const pageRefresh = () => {
    view = resetViewState(); // 
    config = resetPreRegisterConfig();
    fetchProfilelist();

  };
  return {
    DataTable,
    PolicyForm,
    view,
    config,
    fetchProfilelist,
    pageRefresh
  }
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? Also looking for this.

Comment: @InfoStatus not yet, but you can upvote the question to give it  more possibility to be seen by others, so we get the answer finally

Comment: Be careful, you have naming conflicts with your variables and type names. Variables should be camelCased to dissociate them from your PascalCased types

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`:

```js
  setup() {
    const initialState = {
      name: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: ""
    };

    const form = reactive({ ...initialState });

    function resetForm() {
      Object.assign(form, initialState);
    }

    function setForm() {
      Object.assign(form, {
        name: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        email: "john@doe.com"
      });
    }

    return { form, setForm, resetForm };
  }
```

[See it live on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/set-reset-reactive-object-8rdgz?file=/src/App.vue:317-731)

credits: [taken from here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/1081#issuecomment-621385050)

Comment: this is the typical way and I wished there would be a better answer to this problem, but as they told the answer in vue-next github. it seems there isnt any better  answer yet out there.
thanks you for put your time on it

Comment: Object.assgin() can't reset value to undefined.

Comment: It seems to be required to spread the `initialState` in `const form = reactive({ ...initialState });`. When I just did `const form = reactive(initialState);`, the Object.assign didnt work.

Comment: thank you it working very well vue 3.0.0.

Answer (score 8):

`Object.assign` didn't work for me. (Maybe because I used a shim for the Composition API in Nuxtjs 2?) For anybody that run into the same problem: I had to use a compact loop.

```
  setup() {
    const initialState = {
      name: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: ""
    };

    const form = reactive({ ...initialState });

    function resetForm() {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(initialState)) {
          form[key] = value
        }
    }

    function setForm(values = {name: "John", lastName: "Doe", email: "john@doe.com"}) {
        // only loop with the supported keys of initial state
        for (const key of Object.keys(initialState)) {
          form[key] = values[key]
        }
    }

    return { form, setForm, resetForm };
  }
```

Comment: How can I reset array when use active wrap it?

Comment: Same, but this is so unbelievably ugly to do... I can't believe there isn't another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Citing from the official Vueland Discord server:

*"For what I know, reactive is the old way we use to do reactivity from the Classic API, so to reset the values should be something like:"*

```js
const myData = reactive({
  foo: true,
  bar: ''
})

function resetValues () {
 myData.foo = true
 myData.bar = ''
}
```

Therefore, if you don't change properties you should be able to use `Object.assign()`. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: This is resetting values. I want to replace the entire object

Comment: Then adapt your function with parameters so that it updates the entire object. You can't just replace a whole reactive object, it's a limitation. If you need to do so, a `ref` is what you need

Answer (score 1):

If you have deep objects you can use this trick to reset the values converting them to JSON

```js
setup(){
    const form = ref({
      order: '',
      user:{},
    });
    const defaultForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form));
    form.value.user = {firstname:"Joe", lastname:"Doe"};
    const onSubmit = () => {
      // Reset values to default
      form.value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultForm));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to improve [Roland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509432/5004246) a bit. You can make `initialState` a function to create the initial state every time you need it.

```js
setup () {
  const initialState = () => ({
    name: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: ""
  });

  const form = reactive(initialState());

  function resetForm() {
    Object.assign(form, initialState());
  }

  function setForm() {
    Object.assign(form, {
      name: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      email: "john@doe.com"
    });
  }

  return { form, setForm, resetForm };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use ref instead of reactive?

```
const myData = ref({ xxx: 11 })

// ... After many operations on myData 

// resetData
myData.value = { xxx: 11 }
```

The disadvantage is that you need to add .value when using it in script.
But this is the same as reactive in vue template.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `ref` and want to reset value of a `reactive` variable then you have to take one key variable for reference in the reactive variable, because reinitializing reactive variable directly will cause to loose reactivity in the process.

So to reset the value use extra key variable in reactive variable, see code as below

```
setup() {
    const initialState = {
      name: "",
      email: ""
    };

    const form = reactive({ data: ...initialState });

    function resetForm() {
      form.data = { ...initialState };
    }

    function setForm() {
      form.data = {
        name: "Bahubali",
        email: "bahubali@mahismati.com"
      });
    }

    return { form, setForm, resetForm };
}
```

So basically you are taking `data` as key of your reactive variable and when you want to reset or set your values you just need to change the `form.data` and it will be reactive and refreshes the elements which uses `form.data`.

Comment: So form.data instead of form.value? Might as well use a ref().

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite some problems with the Vue Composition API and `Vuetify 3` (without `setup()`) to reset the values.

That's my solution:

```js
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue'

const contactForm: Ref = ref({
  contactType: '',
  email: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  message: '',
  subject: '',
  terms: false,
  whatever: '',
})
...
<v-btn @click="onReset">Reset</v-btn>
...
const onReset = () => {
  contactForm.value?.reset()
}
```

Thanks to https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/15568#issuecomment-1523304471 for inspiration.