# Reactive in Vue Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

What's the proper way to change the value of a reactive object?
In ref you set equal to value. How to do it with reactive and maintain reactivity?

```
setup() {
  const page = reactive({
    title: "Hello, World!",
    categories: [],
  });

  onMounted(() => {
    page.value = {
      title: "Changed Title",
      categories: ['vue', 'angular']
    }
  })

  return { page };
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't replace the entire object. You either need to use ref or do individual properties of the reactive object.

Comment: I need deeply nested object reactivity. Thought in setting the properties individualy but the objects are dynamic. It should have a better way. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish that with `ref({})`

Comment: Please consider editing the title. It is way too generic - your first sentence of the body tells the problem best. Will answer.

Comment: When I googled, I found your question first. Here is the solution I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184749/how-to-properly-reset-vue-composition-apis-reactive-values/66206627

Comment: @MarkusMadeja Thank you, that solution was posted after my question, you can see my participation in that thread also.