# How to use signature along to reactive hook?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I would like to show the backend error messages on my `Vue` component, so for doing that I have created this component:

```
<template>
  <section class="p-0 d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Right START -->
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-9 mx-auto my-5 position-relative">
          <!-- Shape Decoration END -->
          <div class="row h-100">
            <div
              class="
                col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-5
                text-start
                mx-auto
                d-flex
                align-items-center
              "
            >
              <div class="w-100">
                <h3>Sign up for your account!</h3>
                <p>
                  Join us today! Create your account easily with less
                  information.
                </p>
                <!-- Form START -->
                <form class="mt-4" @submit.prevent="submit">
                  <!-- Email -->
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input
                      v-model="data.name"
                      v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': validate.email }"
                      required
                      type="email"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="email"
                      aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                      placeholder="E-mail"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {{ validate.email }}
                    </div>
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"
                      >We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small
                    >
                  </div>
                  <!-- Username -->
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="email">Username</label>
                    <input
                      v-model="data.username"
                      v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': validate.username }"
                      required
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="username"
                      placeholder="Username"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {{ validate.username }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Password -->
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                      v-model="data.password"
                      v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': validate.password }"
                      required
                      type="password"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="password"
                      placeholder="*********"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {{ validate.password }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Password -->
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="password2"
                      >Confirm Password</label
                    >
                    <input
                      v-model="data.password2"
                      v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': validate.password2 }"
                      type="password"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="password2"
                      placeholder="*********"
                    />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {{ validate.password2 }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Checkbox -->
                  <div class="mb-3 form-check">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      class="form-check-input"
                      id="remember"
                    />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember"
                      >keep me signed in</label
                    >
                  </div>
                  <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-line">
                        Sign me up
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 text-sm-end">
                      <span class="text-muted"
                        >Already have an account?
                        <a href="/login">Signin here</a></span
                      >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <!-- Form END -->
                <div class="bg-dark-overlay-dotted py-2 my-4"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Right END -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive, ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Register",
  setup(props) {
    const data = reactive({
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password2: "",
    });

    const validate = reactive({
      email: "",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      password2: "",
    });

    const router = useRouter();

    const submit = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/auth/register`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });

      if (!res.ok) {
        const errors = await res.json().then((response) => response.errors);

        for (const err of errors) {
          const param: string = err.param ?? "";
          validate[param] = err.msg;
        }
      }

    };

    return {
      data,
      validate,
      submit,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

as you can see I have defined and also exposed the `validate` property, which contains all the fields of the `form`.

When the API call is executed on the form submit, I reiceve this response if the backend validation fails:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": "",
            "msg": "username must be at least 4 characters long",
            "param": "username",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "value": "test@",
            "msg": "password confirm is different",
            "param": "password2",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

I binded the `validate` property to each input field, so if the value entered in a specific field is incorrect, an error will be appended near the field and also the `is-invalid` class of `Bootstrap` is applied.

The `errors` variable contains the response above, what I'm trying to do is assign to each property of `validate` (which are the same name of the fields), the error messages, and I did:

```
const param: string = err.param ?? "";
validate[param] = err.msg;
```

the problem's that I get:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ email: string; username: string; password: string; password2: string; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ email: string; username: string; password: string; password2: string; }'.

How can I fix this situation? And also, is there a better way to handle such scenario? 'cause I'm new to `Vue` and most probably I'm overcomplicating the situation here.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decided to add TypeScript to your project, it would be a good idea to start using it as intended, so let's firstly make a type for your error object:

```
type MyTypedError = {
      value: string,
      msg: string, 
      // the question mark indicates that the "param" property may not exists
      // "typeof" infers the type of the "validate" variable (object in your case)
      // "keyof" grabs all the property names from "validate":
      param?: keyof typeof validate,
      location: string
    }
```

Let's make use of it. Now the TypeScript compiler will know the type of the received data.

```
if (!res.ok) {
    // specify the type of the "errors" variable:
    // MyTypedError[] (array of MyTypedError objects)
    const errors: MyTypedError[] = await res.json().then((response) => response.errors);

    ...
}
```

The problem with your code: you are only guaranteeing that the `param` variable is type of `string`, but you don't promise the compiler that `param` holds any of the property names from `validate`. But since the compiler knows the type of `err`, it will even guide you how to make a working loop:

```
for (const err of errors) {
   // We stated that 'param' property might not exist
   if (err.param !== undefined) validate[err.param] = err.msg
}
```

EDIT: The assumption that `err.param` can also be `undefined` came from your code: `err.param ?? ""`, though I don't see any reason why would it be.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer, I did what you said but I still get the error on this:  `validate[err.param] = err.msg;` in particular: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ email: string; username: string; password: string; password2: string; }'.`
Maybe I need to apply the type also to `reactive` hook?

Comment: I tested myself the code I provided and it works properly, so most likely you didn't implement it properly. If you want to choose the simplest way to solve it, then instead of `const param: string = err.param ?? ""` do `const param = err.param as keyof typeof validate`. In my editor the error is gone and the code compiles.

Comment: this is my component: https://pastebin.com/EU60Uuwf and this is the type: https://pastebin.com/LPxUmvFw

Comment: Compare `MyTypedError` from my code with your `ApiError`. They are not the same. Also now I see you are doing: `err.err.validate[err.param] = err.msg` in a loop - you are only trying to mutate your array of error objects ("Trying", because I really doubt it would run without an error).

Comment: I copied your code to codesanbox and fixed it: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-answer-sfarzoso-nwhq2

Comment: Thanks it's working, last question: is there a way to set validate to initial state when the `submit` method is called? I mean, to clear all the property such as email, username ecc..

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509432/16315484