# How to reset a form in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my form and I want to clear the values after submitting the form,

```
<form @submit.prevent="addNewUser" ref="newUserForm">

<script setup>
 import { ref } from "vue";

 //Reference to new user form
const newUserForm = ref();

//New user form
const userForm = reactive({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    email: "",
    telephone: "",
    address: "",
});

const addNewUser = async () => {
   ...
   newUserForm.reset();
}
</script>
```

This is the way I tried, but this is not working. Am I doing anything wrong here? Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: There's no newSupplierForm, is it the same thing as newUserForm? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. It's unknown what happens inside the form. Generally you want to use v-model for form inputs, then you're able to control their values directly

Comment: Sorry for simplicity I used the newUserForm I forgot to put it there :(

Comment: How is userForm used?

Comment: using v-model to the inputs

Comment: Please, provide this code for clarity, as the supposed solution is affected by the way it works.

Comment: this question is already solved under this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184749/how-to-properly-reset-vue-composition-apis-reactive-values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done in a generic way that isn't specific to forms.

Since initial dataset should exist in order to be assigned at some point, there may be factory function that provides it:

```
const getInitialFormData = () => ({ id: "", ... });

const userForm = reactive(getInitialFormData());

const resetUserForm = () => Object.assign(userForm, getInitialFormData());
```

This way the state is guaranteed to reset even if `userForm` object becomes nested at some point.

Comment: What is the purpose of having `getInitialFormData` as a callable instead of normal object?

Comment: Because new `{ id: "", ... }` object is used in 2 places here, extracting it to a function allows to reuse code

Comment: But if I simply create an object `const getInitialFormData = { id: "", ... };` I can also reuse it two times. I don't see a point of having it as a function instead of simple object.

Comment: That was the point of the question. If you do this and modify this object, you can't use this object for a reset because original object doesn't exist at this time. In order to do this, you need to recreate the original object. This is what getInitialFormData function does. There was a typo in the answer, it actually wasn't defined as a function

Comment: You are not answering my question. I still do not get why it has to be a function. I can define my initial state as plain object `const myInitialState= { id: "", ... }`, and then pass it to the reactive like this `reactive({ ...myInitialState })`. And I can also use it inside reset function with `Object.assign(userForm, myInitialState)`. I tried it and it is working. My question is what is the point of having it as a function?

Comment: You didn't mention that you intend to clone an object with a spread. This is what this answer shows, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73156133/3731501 . And as noted in comments, it wont' work with nested state because a spread results in shallow clone. If you add nested fields like { id: "", foo: { bar ... } }` it will become buggy because `foo` won't reset. A more generic and correct solution is to force deep clone in such case and be cautious in cases when it becomes necessary. Or just use factory function and get more practical solution with the same amount of code

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Somehow this work became so repetitive to me so I made a composable.

```js
/**
Usage:
const {
  form: storeForm,
  reset: storeFormReset
} = useForm({
  name: null,
  position: null,
  content: null
})
 */
export default initialState => {
  const form = reactive({ ...initialState })

  function reset () {
    for (const key in initialState) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(initialState, key)) {
        form[key] = initialState[key]
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    form,
    reset
  }
}
```

This helped me big time. Hope this helps you too. In your case, you can use it like this:

```js
const {
  form: userForm,
  reset: userFormReset
} = initialState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    email: "",
    telephone: "",
    address: "",
});

const addNewUser = async () => {
   ...
   userFormReset();
}
```

Warning: This composable works only if the object is shallow (as mentioned by @EstusFlask). Feel free to make changes in the composable to suit your taste

Comment: Can you update the answer according to my question. I don't understand this much :(. Please try to use comments bro

Comment: Notice that this will work correctly only if initialState is shallow object.

Comment: @Beluga-Meow- I've added sample in your case

Comment: @EstusFlask yess,  the cons. I'll try applying your answer to my composable for better usage. If that's okay 

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your setup. You haven't shown how you deal with the form data. Is it a reactive vue model? If yes - you should set the properties of the model to their default values within the "addNewUser" function and the form will clear. Note that this is a preferable approach.

Alternatively [NOT TESTED], you can place an invisible input of type="reset" and call the click function on that button.

Comment: I have updated my question with my reactive fields

Comment: You mean setting every property by one by one. I already know that. But that's a lot of code repeat. Is there any other way?