# Ref cannot reset vue 3 using script setup?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

This is my code to reset based on this

[How to properly reset Vue Composition Api's reactive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184749/how-to-properly-reset-vue-composition-apis-reactive-values)

[How to reset a form in Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154805/how-to-reset-a-form-in-vue-3)

```
<script setup>
const test=ref([
  id:null,
  nm:null,
  addrs:null,
  city:null,
  state:null
])
const form =reactive({...test});
const resetValue=()=>{
  Object.assign(form, initialState);
  console.log(test.value.id)
}
</script>
```

But value can't reset. Any solution?

Comment: do you mean that `test` is the initial state?

Comment: You have there a dozen correct working answers. If one didn't work, pick another one! https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509432/6310260

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes that's variable

Comment: hey your link is used old vue. i use vue 3. Try the code before you answer my question.  Have you try vue 3 with script setup ? give me your example on sandbox or etc if your link success@Mises

Answer (score 0):

step 1: you should use Object value in ref =

```
const test=ref({
  id:null,
  nm:null,
  addrs:null,
  city:null,
  state:null
})
```

step 2: when you use spread operator for ref value you should write .value =

```
const form =reactive({ ...test.value });
```

Comment: It doesn't serve a good purpose to make `test` a ref

Comment: it doesn't work mr